# $How to determine if this series is convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let the sequence $\{a_n\}$ be defined as follows: 
$$a_n \colon= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n^2} \mbox{ if $n$ is not the square of any positive integer}; \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mbox{ if $n$ is the square of a positive integer}. 
\end{cases} 
$$

Then how to decide if the series $\sum a_n$ converges or not?

Comment: Note all terms of the series are positive, and the series  contains each of the terms $1/\sqrt {1^2}$, $1/\sqrt{2^2}$, $1/\sqrt {3^2}$, $\ldots$.

Comment: you could compare it to the series $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @Christian and what will it give?

Comment: Pardon, I meant $\frac 1n$ . The series is obviously greater than $\frac 1n$, so it does not converge. But I am not 100% sure myself, that's why I just comment

Comment: How is the series "obviously" greater than the harmonic one? What would you do with the $\;\frac1{n^2}\;$ terms?

Comment: You ignore them. If you know that a series is greater than a series of which you know it diverges, then you know your original series diverges too. And $\frac 1n$ is a series which does diverge. 
It's a simple comparison test.
Edit: You just have to show that all the other terms are non-negative, which is rather easy with $\frac 1n^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the terms are positive, 
 So, $a_n=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}=\frac 1 p$ where $p^2=n$. So, it contains a sub-series $\sum \frac 1 n$ which is diverges... so the original series must be diverge.

Comment: "Subseries"? Exlain, please.

Comment: @Timbuc I used the word subseries to realize that the series contains the terms of $\sum \frac 1 n$.. thats all.

Comment: fair enough, but then how do you deduce divergence? You could leave this as a nice, easy exercise to the OP. My point was that "subseries" isn't a very widely used term. +1

Comment: yes.. ur right...@Timbuc